# Azure powershell list assigned backup policy to VM

Tags: azure, powershell, backup, virtual, policy

How can I make a list of all VM's inside my subscriptions including the information of:

- Backup Policy
- Backup Schedule
- Backup times
- Backup Retention (daily, weekly, monthly)

So additional to the result of this
Get-AzVM -Status

Thx

I can get data from vm's and data from recovery services vaults, but not together.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure powershell list assigned backup policy to VM

The command `Get-AzVM -Status` does not show any information about the `VM backup` or the `recovery service vault`. The following are the values of the `Get-AzVM -Status` command.

[image]

To check all `VMs` that are backed up in the recovery service vault, along with their `Backup Schedule`, `Backup Policy`, and `Backup Retention` (daily, weekly, monthly),' details, you can make use of the script below.

```
    $vaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault
    foreach ($vault in $vaults) {
        Write-Host "Vault Name: $($vault.Name)"
        
        # Get all protection policies in the vault
        $policies = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -VaultId $vault.Id -BackupManagementType AzureVM -WorkloadType AzureVM
    
        $containers = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -VaultId $vault.Id
    
        foreach ($container in $containers) {
            $containerName = $container.FriendlyName
    
            Write-Host "   VM Name : $containerName"
    
            $backupItems = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -VaultId $vault.Id -WorkloadType "AzureVM"
    
            foreach ($item in $backupItems) {
                $output = @{
                    "Vault Name" = $vault.Name
                    "Container Name" = $containerName
                    "Backup Item Name" = $item.Name
                    "Backup Policy Name" = $policies.Name
                    "RetentionPolicy Name" = $policies.RetentionPolicy
                    "SchedulePolicy Name" = $policies.SchedulePolicy
                }
    
                New-Object PSObject -Property $output | Format-Table -AutoSize
            }
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thx, in my line for "Backup Policy Name" I see there are 3 policies but there is in fact only 1 active. How can I filter on that one specific:
Backup Policy Name   : {DefaultPolicy, VM-Backup-Policy, EnhancedPolicy}
And I only need "VM-Backup-Policy"